# Async validator causes the form status to stay PENDING

Tags: angular, observable, angular-validation

**EDIT: The switchmap seems to be the culprit. When removing it, the status of my form does no longer stay stuck in Pending. Can anyone explain this ?**

I am using the following factory to **create async validators for my forms**:

```
export function createAsyncValidator(checkFn: (value: string) => Observable<Boolean>, errorMessage: string) {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
        return Observable.timer(500).switchMap(() => {
            return checkFn(control.value)
                .map(result => {
                    return result ? null : { [errorMessage]: true };
                });
        });
    };
}
```

I add it to my form like this:

```
createAsyncValidator(this.asyncValidator, 'Error')
```

Implementation of the validator (example):

```
asyncValidator = (value: string): Observable<Boolean> => {
    if (value === 'test') {
        return Observable.of(true); // THIS CAUSES THE FORM TO BE PENDING
    }    
    return this.http.get('url/'  + value, true); // THIS WORKS
};
```

When my async validator uses a **http call to validate my input, everything works as expected**. However, if I return with **Observable.of(true), the whole form stays in PENDING**

After some research I figured that my Observable is not complete, hence the state PENDING. **How can I return an observable that completes ?**

Comment: The of operator creates an Observable that emits some values you specify as arguments, immediately one after the other, and then emits a complete notification. So I don't think the problem is with of... Does your code inside the map executes when the value is test?

Comment: The switchmap seems to be the culprit. When removing it, the status of my form does no longer stay stuck in Pending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the switchMap with a **flatMap** sovles my problem:

```
export function createAsyncValidator(checkFn: (value: string) => Observable<Boolean>, errorMessage: string) {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
        return Observable.timer(500).flatMap(() => {
            return checkFn(control.value)
                .map(result => {
                    return result ? null : { [errorMessage]: true };
                });
        });
    };
}
```